# Remove Files older than 3 years

Tags: linux, bash, delete-file

I need to remove any file in the directory that is older than 2 years old. It is very important that I keep the newest files and delete the old files.

I have searched and found this.

```
find /path/to/files* -mtime +365 -exec rm {} \;
```

Can I just multiply the number?

```
find /path/to/files* -mtime +1095 -exec rm {} \;
```

Is there a way to add a switch that will print the file name to the screen as it removes it? To make sure it is doing what I am expecting?

I have also found this:

```
find /rec -mtime +365 -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f
```

Is there a major difference between the two?  Is one better than the other? What I have read says that xargs is faster. Would I be able to multiply the mtime number out to a 2nd or 3rd year?

And finally would would I be able to place the code as it is into a cron job that can run daily?

Thank you!

Comment: Close voters, this is clearly programming-related. Not every question that mentions linux belongs on serverfault.

Comment: Sorry I posted this in the wrong place.

Comment: You didn't. Close voters were a bit too zealous. Your question has been reopened now

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Can I just multiply the number?
>
> ```
> find /path/to/files -mtime +1095 -exec rm {} \;
> ```

Yes. And to "echo" before you remove

```
find /path/to/files -mtime +1095 -print
```

Then the version with `-exec rm {} \;` to remove the files (when you are ready).

Comment: How can I print after removing the files to know what and all files are deleted successfully?

Comment: Change `rm` to `rm -v`

Answer (score 2):

```
find /path/to/files* -mtime +1095 -exec rm {} \;
```

That should work fine, you can run a dry a run of this by simply listing the files that are found by the command:

```
find /path/to/files* -mtime +1095 -exec ls {} \;
```

To be safe though I would also add in a -type to ensure that other things dont get deleted:

```
find /path/to/files* -type f -mtime +1095 -exec rm {} \;
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer the second part of your question.

Yes there is a major difference in using -exec or xargs.
-exec starts a new process of rm for every file found. This creates a lot of overhead and can seriously slow down Systems if you delete a lot of files.

xargs creates only as much rm processes as needed, as it creates a command line containing as much files as possible. So only a few rm processes are created.

But both are better than -delete, because delete is unsave

Comment: Could you explain why delete is unsafe please?